# Can't make LiveValidation validMessage empty

Tags: javascript, validation

i am using the [livevalidation](http://livevalidation.com) plugin, and have just switched from the prototype version to the standalone version, and have noticed a change in behaviour.

When a user enters the correct information in a field, i dont want there to be any acknoldgement, so i set:

```
validMessage: ""
```

That worked with the prototype version of the plugin, but with the standalone version, it defaults to the message "Thankyou!"

This is not what i want at all, am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you are not missing anything. It's a bug (?) or simply different behavior between the two versions. In the prototype version, the options are extended (using prototype's `Object.extend` method) with the default options. Since you declare a `validMessage` property (albeit set to the empty string) it won't get replaced by the default value. In the standalone version, on the other hand the `validMessage` option is set with the following code:

```
this.validMessage = options.validMessage || 'Thankyou!';
```

In other words, if `validMessage` is falsy (which the empty string is) set it to the default.

I suppose the workaround is to use " " (single space) as the value for `validMessage`. Or write to the developers and ask for the different behavior to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this worked for me, add a space in between the " ". that forces a blank value.

```
validMessage: " "
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to edit the css:

```
.LV_valid {
    color:#00CC00;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
}

.LV_invalid {
    color:#CC0000;
    display:none;
}
```

basically added display:none; to both messages.